# GetCustomAttributes and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, ef-code-first

How do I skip computred columns when getting properties like this? I can do it for NotMapped, but not sure about `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)`?

```
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public bool AAUProcessing { get; set; }
```

**Skip NotMapped and Computred Columns**

```
var props = typeof(TK).GetProperties()
                    .Where(propertyInfo => !propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute)).Any())
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast it to the correct type (`DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`) and you can inspect it for whatever properties you deem appropriate.

The following example will filter out computed and not-mapped properties:

```
void Main()
{
    var props = typeof(TK).GetProperties()
                    .Where(IsNotMapped)
                    .Where(IsNotComputedColumn)
                    .ToArray();

    foreach (var property in props)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
    }
}

static bool IsNotMapped(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return !propertyInfo
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute))
        .Any();
}

static bool IsNotComputedColumn(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return !propertyInfo
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseGeneratedAttribute))
        .Cast<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>()
        .Any(a => a.DatabaseGeneratedOption == DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
}

public class TK
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public bool IsComputed { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public bool IsIdentity { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool NotMapped { get; set; }

    public bool StandardColumn { get; set; }
}
```

The output is

```
IsIdentity
StandardColumn
```